# Is it possible to take a mask clip and 'connect' it to a specific point on a moving object?

Tags: video, tracking

I have a video clip of a car driving by from left to right. My goal is to add a decal (mask) to the car door.  Right now I am painstakingly moving the mask via X and Y.

Comment: Use the motion tracker and parent your mask to the tracking points.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A mostly automatic way to do what you want is to use a **[Plane Track](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.69/Motion_Tracker)**

The workflow is like this:

Load your video clip in the **Movie Clip Editor**

Create a tracker on your image by clicking while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and pressing  the tracking forward button (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>)

[image]

Track at least four points within your video corresponding with the area you want to paste your "decal" to.

[image]

Select all your trackers, go to the **Solve** tab and open the **Plane Track** control and click on **Create Plane Track**

A new shape will be created. (you might need to adjust the shape to match your needs) The deformation of that plane is controlled by the trackers.

[image]

On the compositor use a **Plane Track Deform** Node (found in the Distort section). Connect it to your decal image, select your video source, camera, plane track, and mix it with the movie clip.

[image]

The decal follows the movement and deformation on the video!

[image]