# Unable to "Create Plane Track"

Tags: tracking

I have created 4 tracks for the decal but am unable to 'create plane track'
Keeps showing me the error below

[image]

Comment: As the error message say: You have to select 4 tracks, but I see 1 track is selected. Simply press >a< to select your 4 tracks :)

Comment: @Poor I was just typing the same!

Comment: @cegaton but your grammar is much better, for sure :)

Answer (score 4):

To create a [plane track](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.69/Motion_Tracker) you need at least 4 trackers, select all of them using <kbd>A</kbd>

[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov/23902#23902