# Create a plane from empties / tracks?

Tags: tracking, masking

I'm doing some motion tracking, and I'm trying to reconstruct (if that's the right word) a house as a mask. I don't want to use the mask editor and set mask keyframes and all that because it seems like it's a lot of work, and I'd rather just create a mesh that more or less matches the shape of the house. I have a few tracks on the house, is there any way for me to create a plane that goes through them? Like, to select three tracks, and then somehow create a plane that intersects all of them?

Comment: Track the elements and parent the mask to the trackers... or use a plane track http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.69/Motion_Tracker

Comment: see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24408/can-a-mask-stick-to-a-shape-in-the-motion-tracker and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23978/unable-to-create-plane-track

Comment: @cegaton, thanks for those! However, none of them exactly answer my question...the first one is about using masks, while I actually want to create a mesh, and the second one is about plane track, but I don't want to do plane track because the house is staying still. That first one might be helpful, at this point I'm just starting to do the old-fashioned masking thing