# Is it possible to make a copy of a plane track

Tags: tracking

[image: airplane]

Currently manually tracking each plane frame by frame due to the tracker not being able to follow I assume due to lack of reference points....can I track 1 plane then simply copy for the remaining 3?

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Not really. But what you could do, at the expense of accuracy, is track any 4 points that are trackable (like the rivets on the fuselage) create the plane track and then just move the plane track points according to your needs. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23902/1853