# Motion tracking an image to go offscreen

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, tracking, movie-clip-editor

Hello Blender Community

I am trying to make images track the heads of characters in a video clip. I can do this fine, but when a character goes offscreen or behind an object, the image doesn't disappear with the track- is there a checkbox I'm missing or something?

Thank you.

Comment: There is  no automatic way to do this. If you want the object to disappear behind something you need to use masks that use the tracked information to hide the foreground layer. To track an object that goes off screen you need to offset the tracker. Read this related link:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/joining-2d-tracking-markers-with-an-offset

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24408/can-a-mask-stick-to-a-shape-in-the-motion-tracker