# Add a 3D ironman mask to a real head

Tags: compositing-nodes

this is my first question ever :) I am a blender beginner so pleaaaase bare with me.

I have a 3D ironman mask that i have downloaded. I have a footage of my daughter and I want to add the 3D ironman mask to her face. In the video, my daughter's head is not still of course.

I have already done the camera track, i have set an HDRi and I have added the iron man mask to my daugther's head but only for the first frame.

Do i need to manually animate the mask to match my son's head movements or is there a cleaner way to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24408/can-a-mask-stick-to-a-shape-in-the-motion-tracker

Comment: welcome! i would recommend to search for "blender track points tutorial" on google ;)

Comment: This is a really good tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDeiup4tgmg

Comment: Thank youuuuuu :D this is what I was looking for exactly :D