# Video clip editor motion tracking masks overlay

Tags: video, tracking, masking, movie-clip-editor

This is the situation:

- I have a video with the following image display on a tablet (you can see the video here [video here](https://videos.pexels.com/videos/android-tablet-swipe-scroll-gesture-344)
- I want to substitute the image you see one the tablet in the video (green background with crossed white/black circles) with an object plane with an image
- Mind that in the video background, there is the hand of the actress that overlay the screen of the tablet (so, obviously, the texture of the plane has to be alpha where the "hand-section" of the movie frames overlay the plane).

My [.blend file is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2t6C4o5L_DjbWtUaURJdVV6VW8/view?usp=sharing). (the video file is not packed, I've already done some camera motion tracking/plane deforming work)

So, my question is:
- is there a more or less automated way / addon in Blender using which I can get my goal?
- any suggestions?

Thanks to anyone ;)

Comment: An automated way to replace the screen? That's difficult since each footage is different. Dependent on your shots, you could only try to speed up the whole process by using a planar tracker like mocha.

Comment: The most automated way is what you are doing. Track the edges, create a plane track and use that to deform the image to be overlaid. see this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov/23902#23902

Comment: @poor .. thanks for your reply ... I will go with blender planar tracking tool

Comment: @cegaton ... thank you for reply ... I've looked the post your linked ... there it doesn't explain how to do if in the video there is an object overlaying the video section I want to modify ... but I found these that helped me
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0U7XE9Sl-g -----
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IezDwsh30ag
Thanks anyway ;)